# Visual studio 2010 database project allowing stored procedure with invalid SQL to build

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, database-project

I have a database project that is specifed as 2005. (This is on the properties screen under the project settings. )

We have several servers we deploy and run against production is 2005 but we have some 2008 R2 servers that we develop against so we specify the project as 2005.

I have added stored proc which I created on a 2008R2 database which is used only for development. It all works fine so I added it to the database project. The project built and deployed fine meaning that it generates the .sql file. We do not apply changes from the VS Project.

We have a CI TFS build that runs against a 2005 database. (we have several configurations and each 'deploys' against a different database). It built and deployed fine. Again it only generated the updates into an SQL file.

The stored proc contains the following code:

```
    insert SiteCAChargeParameterSet
    values (
             ( select siteID 
                 from SiteCAChargeParameterSet
                where SiteCAChargeParameterSetID = @OldSiteCAChargeParameterSet
              ),
                @NewSetName,0,0,@UserID, @currentDate,@UserID, @currentDate
            )
```

All of the variables are defined.
When I try to create this stored proc on the 2005 database I get an error (1046) that indicates that the select is not allowed "Subqueries are not allowed in this context."

My question is why does the compiler permit this. Clearly since I have indicated that this is a sql server 2005 project it should follow rules for that version. Further, since it is comparing against a 2005 database for the deploy is should also know that this is illegal.

I am hoping thereis an option somewhere that I don't have turned on or something like that. 
Or is this just an error in the SQL 'compiler'.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so, try editing the Target Connection on the Debug tab of your project properties page and make sure it is pointing to a SQL 2005 database.

That will ensure that VS does a check against the proper SQL version for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the compatibility level of the Database on your 2008r2 server to 90 (SQL Server 2005).

```
ALTER DATABASE <database_name>
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
```

This may allow the detection of the incompatible sub select.